# Matlab - how can I label variables?

Tags: matlab, variables, label

I have a matrix with population data and a vector that makes reference to each type of data example, age, country, gender, height, ethnicity.
 I need to in a part of the code, use those strings as char 1x1. I thougnt in making some relation as

```
variables =  {'age', 'a';
           'gender', 'b';
          'country', 'c';
           'height', 'd';
        'ethnicity', 'e'};
```

I would like something that any time I use the leters, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' or 'e', the code understands that I want to use 'age', 'gender', 'country', 'height' or 'ehtnicity', respectively.

how could I do this?
thanks!

Comment: sounds like you could use the [`dataset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html) class from the Statistics toolbox

Comment: I have no toolbox in my matlab package :/

Comment: `dataset` class is nothing but a convenient wrapper around cell arrays, which fancier indexing and a mapping to retrieve columns by name (plus a few other useful functions). You could do it yourself. But first, can you describe your data matrix and stored types

Comment: I tryied, but I didn't arrived in something that works. This data set is a bunch of numbers. even the things that are names, as countries, gend... are numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

A more common method is to use a structure:

```
codes.a = 'age';
codes.b = 'gender';
...
```

So anytime you need a code, just get the value of the equivalent structure member:

```
character_you_typed = 'a';
getfield(codes, character_you_typed)
```

or (based on @Amro 's comment below):

```
codes.(character_you_typed)
```

This method does not restrict you to one-character keys. Another method is to use the recently added Map container with a 'char' key:

```
codes = containers.Map('KeyType', 'char');
codes('a') = 'age';
codes('b') = 'gender';
...
```

Then:

```
character_you_typed = 'a';
codes(character_you_typed)
```

The second method looks much better, but unfortunately you are restricted to a single character for the keys.

Comment: for the first option, you could also use dynamic field names: `codes.('a')`. A third option is to manually maintain a mapping using cell arrays and string searching to retrieve the associated codes

Comment: @Amro great point about dynamic field names. I added that to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: btw maps are not restricted to single chars: `containers.Map({'aa','bb'}, {'age','gender'})`

Comment: Expanding on what @Amro said, the field names can also be stored in a cell themselves. The corresponding structure can than be accessed as follows: ``NAMES = {'a1'; 'b22'}`` and now use ``NAMES{2,1}`` to access a hypothetical field ``codes.b22``: ``codes.(NAMES{2,1})``. This can be expanded to work inside loops. If the loop counter was ``i=3`` and ``NAMES{3,1} = 'c'``, then a field ``codes.c3`` could be accessed like this: ``codes.([NAMES{3,1},num2str(i)])``

Comment: I got the point. Thanks guys, guys. But if I want to read some of those values as cell array?

Saying something like a b c and having  `{'age, 'gender', 'country'}`

Comment: OK if `a='a'; b='b'; c='c';` then `{codes.(a), codes.(b), codes.(c)}` gives you what you want.

Comment: ok, you put the braces before and at the end. i didn't notice it. many thanks again.